# Change dialog styles in Android

Tags: java, android, styles

How can I change the style of all dialogs in my application?

My app is using some of "material dark theme" -> I don't know WHY, and all dialogs have "ugly gray" color and I can't change it!

I tried it over:

```
super(context, R.style.my_super_dialog_style);
```

But I can't change my preferences like that!

I'm using:

1. alert dialog
2. progress dialog
3. list preference (where is also dialog after click -> with options)
4. multiselectpreference (just like 3.)
5. texteditpreference

And I need to change:

1. background color
2. title color
3. message color
4. progress color (optional, it's the same color for 4,6,7)
5. positive / negative button text color (optional, I'm changing it via java)
6. checkbox active color (optional, it's the same color for 4,6,7)
7. radio active color (optional, it's the same color for 4,6,7)

Incidentally, when I finally thought I found the color (via "Theme Editor"), the color can not be edited cause it's read only! When I make a copy of that style, it does not work.

Comment: make custom dialog for your app...for that you have to make xml (UI layout) file and inflate it in your dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dialog with your custom layout.

First of all create custom layout for your dialog

for instance

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dialogrectangle">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sub_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="dimen/marginTop"
    android:textSize="@dimen/invalidSize"
    />




<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginBottom="dimen/marginBotom"
    android:src="@drawable/okay"/>
```

After that Create Dialog class

```
public class ViewDialog {
public void showDialog(View activity,int width,int height){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity.getContext());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

    ImageView dialogButton = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okay);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();

    window.setLayout(width, height);

}
}
```

then use these lines to show dialog where you want show

```
 ViewDialog dialog = new ViewDialog();

 dialog.showDialog(view,width,height);
```

Let me know if that helps. :)

Comment: In this way I must also create custom text edit preference, listpreference, multiselect preference.. it's the same like just set custom style via constructor.

Comment: Yes you are right you need custom layouts for everyones.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must define your own theme style. It is not possible to change required properties only in some property window.

Comment: Yeah, I know.. but how? (To make it work for every component)